# Shortest path creation between two lines

Tags: qgis, line, arcgis-10.4, matlab, perpendicular

I've a raster of temperature of a river, I'd like to extract values horizontally, so from bank to bank, shortest path. so basically extract pixel values along the red lines in the schema I did. What is the easiest way to generate these red lines ?

[image: diagram river]

I've Arcgis 10.4, Qgis, matlab. Tried a lot of stuff already but nothing convincing, I extracted the banks and transformed the lines to points, numbered them and planned to joint #1 from left bank to #1 of right bank, but that doesn't creates shortest path. Then I wanted to create perpendicular lines to every point, taking a line between precedent and successive point as a reference, but my coding skills in matlab are insufficient.

I want use these extracted data to calculate lateral STD and different stats.

Comment: Which of QGIS, ArcGIS Desktop and Matlab do you wish to ask about in this particular question?  Once you have decided that you will be much better placed to describe precisely what you have tried with that software.

Comment: well any software that will bring a solution is fine.

Comment: I think the term "skeletonization" will provide you some paths to follow if nothing else useful comes up.

Comment: @RaphaelVallat you need to cut and paste your question into four separate questions, then edit so each one says precisely one of "using ArcGIS", "using Matlab", "using QGIS" or (if you want) "using R". Them's the rules. I don't make them.

Comment: Search for "perpendicular transects", you will find a few ArcGIS solutions.

Comment: @Spacedman and also describe what the asker has tried and where they are stuck with each software. Too broad is there to prevent outsourcing preliminary research to the volunteer community.